# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Tried following:

- remove package compat v7 and readded
- clean bin & obj folder, rebuild.
- repaired vs 2017
- added "android:" prefix but no luck, reverted
- added "@style" prefix no luck, reverted

still had following problems. Anyone have any idea?

[image]

Comment: Check in your style.xml file 
 `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/yourColorCode</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/yourColorCode</item> 
 <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourColorCode</item>

 </style>`

Comment: Check in your app gradle, Have you added required implementations 

   
      `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'`

Comment: @RakeshKumar  forget to mention. it is Xamarin.

Comment: Sorry, no problem. :)

Comment: @RakeshKumar thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @hmmheng, Welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

turned out to Xamarin.* packages in v25.3.1 are problematic, Microsoft's VS support team helped to solve it by updating those packages to v27.*.
it is weird that older machine works fine with v25.3.1.